# Statically link to vcruntimexxx.dll while dynamically link to ucrtbase.dll with Cmake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, cmake

When building Visual C++ with `cl.exe` in command line, I can do this with `cl /MT /GL main.cpp /link /LTCG /NODEFAULTLIB:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib`. I can verify the result by running `tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq main.exe"`, the list will contain ucrtbase.dll but not vcruntimexxx.dll as expected.

Now my real problem: I want to build https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen like above. I added the following in the main CMakelists.txt:

```
  ADD_COMPILE_FLAG("/MT")
  ADD_COMPILE_FLAG("/GL")
  ADD_LINK_FLAG("/LTCG")
  ADD_LINK_FLAG("/NODEFAULTLIB:libucrt.lib")
  ADD_LINK_FLAG("ucrt.lib")
```

The programs built still dynamically linked to vcruntimexxx.dll.

How to do this with CMake?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such commands in CMake. Use [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_compile_options.html) instead of `ADD_COMPILE_FLAG` and [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html) for `ADD_LINK_FLAG`.